# Behavior of setWillNotDraw(false) in View

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas

I am new comer to the android and got stuck with this concept.

I have extended `FrameLayout` and added child views. My child view's `onDraw` is called even without setting `setWillNotDraw(false)`. Then what is the actual need of it and when this flag should be set.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`setWillNotDraw` is not required in a `View` class.

However, it is usually set to `true` in a `ViewGroup`. Therefore, is disables the `onDraw` method there.

If you need the `onDraw` method to be called inside a `ViewGroup`, you just set the flag to `false` like so: `setWillNotDraw(false)`.

Also, if you don't want that `onDraw` in your view's subclass to be called, you have to call `subclassInstance.setWillNotDraw(true)`