# Why onDraw() is not called if Custom View extends ViewGroup?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

A have a custom view. This view works on principle `ListView`, but all items draws on Canvas, so they are not are children of `ViewGroup`. Say more: my View is not a `ViewGroup`, it extends `View`. Now I want to use `Adapter` interface to provide data to my view via `getView(...)` method. **But**. I have been stucked with drawing issue. I trying to change my extending from `View` into `ViewGroup` and here is my confusing. `onDraw()` method is not called! I really want to avoid posting my code, that works under *NDA*, so I want to know - is the `ViewGroup` drawing logic not the same if we extends from `View`, not from `ViewGroup`?

Comment: Maybe its this what let you stuck ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34374363/behavior-of-setwillnotdrawfalse

Answer (score 11, accepted):

that's the expected behavior, unless the flag `setWillNotDraw` is forced to false. ViewGroup are not expected to do any drawing on their own, but to delegate the drawing to their children. If you want to override this behavior, you can either call `setWillNotDraw(false)` or override `dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)` instead of `onDraw`

Comment: not really, it simply skips `onDraw()` method, it still draws its own background for example

Comment: @pskink however it helps in my case, thanks for your 0.02$.

Comment: @SergeyShustikov three, 3 cents or 0.78 hryvnia ;-)